# Windows 10 icons become blank when they are large

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails

I have windows 10 on my HP laptop. A problem happend to all my Thumbnails some days ago. Now all large-sized Icons are blank. Folders, Images, Document,... All are blank. If I make them small, they are as expected.

> Windows 10
>    - Version: 1803 
>    - OS Build: 17134.285

You can see the problem in these images:

**Large Icons:**

[image]

**Small icons:**

[image]

Comment: These icons are resources embedded in Windows DLL files, so cannot really disappear without damage to your system. Try to do [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Such a wonderful tool. But it found just one problem and it was about mscormmc.dll. And after a restart the problem still exists

Comment: `mscormmc.dll` is part of the Microsoft .NET Runtime. I suggest to download and install [.NET Framework 4.7.2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime), to ensure it's in order. Who knows, it might even help with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

### The Three Steps I Used

I've had this issue a few times in the past.

These are the things I usually do to fix.

1. Restart the computer.
2. Update graphics driver.
3. Delete `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local` > `IconCache.db`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work for me. The driver is the latest already and deleting that file did not help

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for everyone. Apparently, it's also a Windows bug on some systems where icons have scaling issues on some systems/monitors. It's been ongoing since 2017. Windows support trying to dodge the issue when challenged in support questions.

Comment: But I  didn't have this problem two weeks ago and I didn't updated windows since then

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happens to me, that's what helped me fix it:

- Run **regedit**
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

  - look for **IconServiceLib** REG_SZ, in my case that key is not existed.
  - Create/update it with `IconCodecService.dll`
- Repeat same for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

That's it, large icons appears without any other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution in some forum and it worked for me:
1. Open notepad (or any editor).
2. Enter the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90"
```

3. Save the file as .reg
4. Double click the file to import into registry

Comment: This fixed the registry entries mentioned by smbdevin

Comment: Are all these registry entries strictly necessary to fix the problem? Some of them look a bit unrelated to icons.

Comment: I'm not sure, but for me, the issue is fixed. I'll let someone with more knowledge on the topic answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution in some forum and it worked for me: 1. Open notepad (or any editor). 2. Enter the following:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90" 
Save the file as .reg
Double click the file to import into registry